# Android override web view when http error occurs

Tags: android, http

The web view that I am connecting to is capable of handling all request errors, but if a server error occurs, such as a 500 error, there is nothing I can do on the server side to make it gracefully handle the error. I want to add some code within the app so that if a fatal error occurs the app can handle it and give a simple message that says click here to try again.

Ideally I would like to just inject and override the existing content returned in the web view and use some custom html that lets me redirect to a contact form or something if the issue persists. So far I have the following method.

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
    switch(errorCode)
    {
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_UNKNOWN:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS:

            break;
    }
}
```

I dont know what I need to do from here to override the standard response from the web view that gives the http error information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override the webview onReceivedError method.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            switch(errorCode)
    {
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_CONNECT:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_REDIRECT_LOOP:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_UNKNOWN:

            break;
        case WebViewClient.ERROR_TOO_MANY_REQUESTS:

            break;
    }
    }
 });
```

Comment: thanks for the response, my issue with this comes after this point. i dont know i should go about overriding the web view so that it doesnt display the standard http response screen if a server error occurs